# toString vs String in Swift

Tags: string, swift, tostring

I was hoping someone could clarify for me if there's a difference between toString() and String() in Swift.

**Examples:**

```
var myInteger: Int
myInteger = 9

let myString1 = "I like to play " + toString(myInteger) + "-ball pool"

let myString2 = "I like to play " + String(myInteger) + "-ball pool"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference for the example you've given, because `String` has a constructor that will take an `Int`. (`String(...)` is a constructor for the `String` type, not a function.) Try it with a `Double` and you'll get a compiler error.

`toString()`, however, can take an instance of *any* type - there are no constraints on its generic parameter. It's essentially the same as using string interpolation to convert an instance to a string, but in function form:

```
**Swift 3**
let myNumber = 3.3
let myNumberString = String(myNumber)
let myInterpolatedString = "\(myNumber)"
// both are "3.3"
```